# File won't open

Tags: c++

---

code now runs but won't open the file
I am also new with files so I don't know how to get the file to open but the prime number works and give me the prime number part but the file will not open.

anyone know how to fix this?

here is the revised code

```
   #include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
//function prototype
bool isPrime(int number);
int main()
{
    //declare variable to store input
    //from user
    int number;
    //declare variable to store
    //function output
    bool result;
    //prompt user to enter his number
    //then read from keyboard
    cout << "Enter your number, and I will check";
    cout << " whether it is prime or not!\n";
    cin >> number;
    //call function and save its output in variable
    //passing the user number as argument
    result = isPrime(number);
    //use if/else statement to determine whether
    //to print is prime, or is not prime
    if(result)
        cout << "The number " << number << " is prime!\n";
    else
        cout << "The number " << number << " is not prime!\n";
    return 0;
}

bool isPrime(int number)
{
    //start checking from 2 onwards
    //until number-1, because dividing by 1
    //and number will always be evenly divisible
    for(int divisor = 2; divisor <= number-1; divisor++)
    {
        //if an operation up until some point
        //returns 0, means that the number if evenly
        //divisible by some other number other than
        //1 and itself, so return false
        if(number % divisor == 0)
            return false;
    }
    //if the whole loop has finished and function has not
    //terminated by return statement, it means that number
    //is prime so return true
    return true;
}
void outputPrimes(int number)
{

    //create and open output file
    ofstream outputfile("primeNumbers.txt");
    cout << "I will write a list of the prime numbers\n";
    cout << "from 1 to 100 in a file named \"primeNumbers.txt\"!\n\n";

    //use for loop to call function for numbers
    //from 1 to 100
    for(int counter = 1; counter < 100; counter++)
    {
        if(isPrime(counter))
            outputfile << counter << endl;
    }




   //tell user program has terminated and file
    //has been written
    cout << "File has been written!\n";

    //return 0 to mark successful termination


    //start checking from 2 onwards
    //until number-1, because dividing by 1
    //and number will always be evenly divisible
    for(int divisor = 2; divisor <= number-1; divisor++){
        //if an operation up until some point
        //returns 0, means that the number if evenly
        //divisible by some other number other than
        //1 and itself, so return false
        if(number % divisor == 0)

    }
    //if the whole loop has finished and function has not
    //terminated by return statement, it means that number
    //is prime so return true

}
```

is there a way to open the file and give the prime number
If anyone could help that would be great.

Thanks So Much

---

Comment: Do you need those 2 versions of `isPrime`? If so, you should rename them since they do different things anyway.

Comment: ***If so, you should rename them since they do different things anyway*** Agreed, the second implementation is completely different from the first. It should not be named isPrime() at all. The second deals with files and should call the first to produce the result. The first should be isPrime() and the 3rd implementation should be deleted because its the same as the first.

Comment: what should I rename the second?

Comment: Choosing a name is a user preference. You could try the following signature: `void outputPrimes()` since you don't use the parameter in the second function at all and don't need a return value.

Comment: got rid of return values and got this error code. expected primary-expression before ‘}’ token

Comment: There is no way I could possibly help with that error without seeing the exact code you are using.

Comment: code is in edit

Comment: After `cout << "File has been written!\n";` you should have `}` and the rest of the code following that deleted. Also I am confused now because your code does not use `outputPrimes` at all is writing all of the prime numbers less than 100 to a file even part of the assignment? That is what outputPrimes() does.

Comment: writing prime numbers is part of the assignment

Comment: Then you need to change your main to call outputPrimes() at some point. Your main() all about asking the user if a single number is prime.

Answer (score 2):

It's telling you exactly what the problem is: you're redefining the implementation of the function `bool isPrime(int)`. You currently have three definitions for that function so you need to get rid of two of them.

Edit: I will also point those functions don't return the correct type at the end. The function should return `bool` but you're returning an `int`.

Comment: "_The function should return `bool` but you're returning an `int`._" Technically, the `int` value will be implicitly converted to a bool (`0` to `false`; anything else to `true`). That, however, may, or may not be, intentional.

Comment: which two should I get rid of?

Comment: It depends which one you want to keep. First and third appear to be the same but the second one is written a bit differently.

Comment: I took out the first and third and this error code came up

Comment: main.cpp:31:1: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘{’ token

Comment: I believe that means you made a mistake on how much you deleted.

Comment: The second one probably should have been named differently. It does not make sense to call itself recursively.

Comment: The first and third are the same but have an error. `return 0;` is wrong. It needs to be changed to do what the comment says.

Comment: tried that and got the same errors. computer dying coming back tomorrow to finsh it

Comment: now this error code is coming up. main.cpp:48:6: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘)’ token

Comment: That’s for a different reason now. I believe @drescherjm is right and you probably didn’t delete something correctly. Check your code and make sure you have balanced braces and whatnot.

Comment: I changed 'return 0;' to 'return false;' and am still getting the redefinition error codes.

Comment: You didn’t delete the correct parts of your code again. There should be exactly one function named `isPrime`.

Answer (score 0):

you're redefining(2 times) the implementation of the function bool isPrime(int).Are you trying to implement function overloading. Even the the output will not be correct,since you are returning int instead of bool.Technically,the int will value will be converted to a bool,but the output will not be as expected.

Comment: how can I fix this?